# How remove axis, connect dots with a line, and add fillOpacity to the legend in Altair?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have seen various responses in threads here and on Github which mention that some manual alterations can be made to an Altair graph by using CSS, but I am unsure how one would go about doing this. Specifically, I have the following code and graph:

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_circle(opacity=1, stroke='#4c78a8').encode(
    x='Paragraph:N',
    y=alt.Y('Section:N', sort=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data['Section']))),
    size='algo_score_normalized:Q',
    fillOpacity=alt.FillOpacity(
        'fill:Q',
        scale=None
    )
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400
)
```

[image]

I would like to make the following changes:

1. Get rid of the x-axis completely so there is no label or line
2. Change the legend to have different values and for the filling of the legend circles
   to match the filling of the circles in the graph (i.e. below 0.4 is not filled).
3. I'd like to draw horizontal lines connecting all the circles in a given row (kind
   of like a network graph).

Can these be done either natively or using CSS?

Comment: At least some of these can be done natively (maybe all). Could you create a fully reproducible example including sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the axis via `axis=None` and use `mark_rule` to connect the dots with a line. However, [VegaLite does not support `fillOpacity` in the legend](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4982) so you would have to use a workaround, e.g. creating a point and a circle mark as in my example below.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


cars = data.cars().sample(10, random_state=239)
fills = alt.Chart(cars.query('Cylinders > 4')).mark_circle(size=200, opacity=1).encode(
    x=alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', axis=None),
    y='Cylinders:O',
    color='Cylinders:O'
)

fills_rule = alt.Chart(cars.query('Cylinders > 4')).mark_rule(stroke='#5ba3cf').encode(
    x=alt.value(190),
    y='Cylinders:O'
)


strokes = alt.Chart(cars.query('Cylinders == 4')).mark_point(size=200, opacity=1).encode(
    x=alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', axis=None),
    y='Cylinders:O',
    color=alt.Color('Cylinders:O', title='')
)

strokes_rule = alt.Chart(cars.query('Cylinders == 4')).mark_rule(stroke='#5ba3cf').encode(
    x=alt.value(385),
    y='Cylinders:O'
)

(fills_rule
 + fills
 + strokes_rule
 + strokes
).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Is there a way to edit the legend to have specific words, however? For instance, if instead of "Cylinders," I wanted the legend title to be "Number of Matches," or if I wanted the actual legend marks to say "4 matches" and "8 matches."

Comment: @MurtazaAli You're welcome! You can use the `title` param of the encoding (in this case `alt.Color(title='Number of Matches')`. I am not sure about appending "matches" to each label, so please as a new question on SO about that and mark this one as resolved.